# 403 when trying to view s3 files / images

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have the s3 url saved to my mongoose object, then on the client side, i'm attempting to use this s3 url as an  src.

I keep getting a 403.

I've looked at a few similar questions, which state I need to configure my permissions / policy.

I've done that:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "UploadFile",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::acct#:root"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::whiskey-upload/*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "crossdomainAccess",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::whiskey-upload/crossdomain.xml"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllowPublicRead",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::whiskey-upload/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Any clue on what else I may be doing wrong?

Comment: Looks like it should be okay. Are you sure whatever you're using to upload is using the AWS key + secret for your root account?

Comment: I believe so. I can see the uploaded images if I log into AWS, just not on my web app, though.

Comment: however, i'm not authenticating any request to view / display the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have it as http://www. As a prefix in src it wont work. I had encountered such problem before. You can test this directly too. Suppose you have an image src to the s3 bucket. Try to view the image on web browser with www. And without www. Prefix. You might understand better.

But if its directly s3.url then it should work. Please show me the src url that you have to debug the issue.

Comment: I don't think that's the issues. it's just https as the prefix.

Comment: No i mean www. As a prefix. Just try once and see. If it works. Bcoz i was creating url in excel and dumping the image url. I had to add www. Inorser for excel to show the hyperlink but it seemed the www. Prefix broke the url and i had 403 error

Comment: You're saying it should be:             <td><img ng-src="www.https://s3.amazonaws.com/.jpg"></td>

?

Comment: Yes. Try without www. So here it would be s3.amazonaws.com/...etc. or http://s3.amazonaws.com/...etc

Comment: it was a prefixed directory issue. not the exact right answer, but you helped me find my dumb mistake. THX.